# Google Drive Android - OAuth Consent screen showing wrong app name

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-signin

I have integrated google drive in my app using OAuth. Everything is working fine except my consent screen for drive access is showing wrong app name, "QuickStart". I have also setup a consent screen on console.
Strangely it shows correct name and app icon on login screen.

Can anyone please suggest anything about it.

Comment: If you did set another name to show in your consent screen, I'd suggest contacting G Suite support: https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213

Comment: In any case, where did you set up the name to show in the consent screen? Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I did setup on consone in set up OAuth Consent screen.